# warning: line editing not enabled

Tags: bash

I found this helpful command `bind -x '"\C-r"':reset` to clear the terminal but I wanted to make a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
bind -x '"\C-r"':reset
```

**output:**

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/bash$ ./bind 
./bind: line 2: bind: warning: line editing not enabled
```

Could someone please explain:

1. How can I fix this?
2. What does `warning: line editing not enabled` mean?

Comment: I fixed this already using `echo -e '\0033\0143'` thanks to http://superuser.com/questions/122911/bash-reset-and-clear-commands/123007#123007, but I still would like to know what this error means and how to fix this. Many thanks.

Comment: @squircle thanks for good improvements. Might you also know answer to my question :P?

Comment: Just for the record (because this hasn't really been answered): you get "line editing not enabled", because in the bash that is spawned when you invoke your script it simply isn't enabled and you have to do it yourself, .e.g by inserting a `set -o emacs` or `set -o vi` into your script (before the `bind`, of course).

Comment: could try piping it to dev null. bind -x '"\C-r"':reset 2>/dev/null;

Comment: Just use Ctrl+L

Comment: @kingsjester that just clears the screen. Reset does that, but in addition, it also resets the terminal to its normal state, in case you or some application messed with its state/capabilities.

Comment: @ychaouche thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to source that script. Do `. ./bind` or `source ./bind` to make that key binding active in the current session.

Running it normally, it doesn't have a terminal so it gives you that error message. Also, if it were to work, it would only be active for the duration of the script.

If you want that keybinding to be persistent, add that command to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: 1. I know about the persistence. 2. Your example does work, but adds complexity running command(in my opinion). I guess I now know this, but I would like to have a simple bash file which I can run without this `source`.

Comment: @alfredwesterveld: If you don't want the binding loaded every time you start a shell, but you want to be able to activate it any time without having to use `source` or dot (`.`), add a function to your `~/.bashrc`: `rbind () { bind -x '"\C-r"':reset; }` then you can enter `rbind` by itself as a command and the binding will be activated.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar message but mine was from a script being run outside of an interactive (login) shell; it was a shell script being run via a CGI script.  My message was:

```
/home/richard/.bash_profile: line 4: bind: warning: line editing not enabled
```

and although it wasn't actually on line 4, the only `bind` in that file was:

```
bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'
```

which of course only makes sense if line editing is enabled, i.e. if it's an interactive shell.

Comment: [Here's how to avoid the warning](https://superuser.com/a/892682).

Comment: @Casimir Thanks; I also found [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f) which seems to be the "official" method of detecting whether a shell is interactive.

Answer (score 8):

Just trying to improve the accepted answer.

You get "`line editing not enabled`" when running in a non-interactive shell, because `bind` requires a TTY.

Wrap your `bind` commands in a check like this:

```
if [ -t 1 ]
then
    # standard output is a TTY
    bind -x '"\C-r"':reset
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment the answer of rustyx. So I add an answer instead but just improving the answer of rustyx.

Using test "-t 1" to check if bind will work is not enough. See [Remote SSH Commands - bash bind warning: line editing not enabled](https://superuser.com/questions/892658/remote-ssh-commands-bash-bind-warning-line-editing-not-enabled) for explanation and also some improved checks.

What worked best for me for Bash was using one of the checks described in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f :

- test if $PS1 is not zero
- test if $- contains "i"

E.g.

```
if [ "$PS1" ] ; then
  # shell is interactive
  bind -x '"\C-r"':reset
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I would test if the shell is interactive instead.
Here's a block of code I found in my distro's bashrc file

```
# Test for an interactive shell.  There is no need to set anything
# past this point for scp and rcp, and it's important to refrain from
# outputting anything in those cases.
# if [[ $- != *i* ]] ; then
#   # Shell is non-interactive.  Be done now!
#   return
# fi
```