# Is there a command to clear a Cygwin console?

Tags: windows, cygwin

Is there a command to clear all of the history in a Cygwin console window without losing the `.bash_history`?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/240337/clearing-terminal), except that it isn't as well written.  If you had written your question better, Erik Vold, without misnaming terminal output as "history" for starters, you wouldn't have had to explain what you were asking over and over in comments.  This should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @JdeBP did you try the solution mentioned there? it does not work..

Comment: @JdeBP Cygwin != *nix console... So, no dupe IMHO... Please don't be too harsh, try to be constructive in your criticism...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click `Ctrl-L`. It should clear everything without losing the .bash_history.
`

Comment: If necessary, you could embed ^L in a script, or even change the Bash prompt to clear the screen after each command.

Comment: Doesn't this just move previous output off screen?

Answer (score 6):

If you mean you want to clear the console window: install ncurses (in Utils) and then you can use:

```
clear
```

Answer (score 1):

Open Windows Explorer then navigate to:

> [Cygwin Installation Directory]\home\[User]\

`e.g.:  C:\cygwin\home\wreckseal`

then open the file `.bashrc` with Notepad++.

Move your cursor at the end of the last line and hit `Enter` key, then add the text below.

> alias cls='echo -e "\033c"'

or the text below:

> alias cls='printf "\033c"'

Restart cygwin, type `cls`.  Done!

Note that there's no scrollbar after sending the cls command. I prefer the `printf` version than the `echo` version. Try it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> and the screen is like you have just open a fresh cygwin!

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways:

1. Type the command `clear`
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>