# How do I clear my bash screen while maintaining scrollback?

Tags: bash

The `clear` command can make the next command easier to read (if it outputs less than a page there's no scrolling hence no searching for the beginning). However it also clears the scrollback buffer which you may not always want.

Comment: See @Guillermo answer below:  command >  clear -x

Comment: @Capybara now, the name was changed

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just press Ctrl-L on the keyboard.

Comment: Current behavriou of ctrl-l in cygwin bash erase scrollback as well.

Comment: It's not working in Windows

Answer (score 14):

#### TL;DR

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to scroll the current line to the top. The scrollback is not erased.
- `clear -x` to erase the all the lines that are not in the scrollback.
- `clear` to erase all the lines, including the scrollback.

---

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> [is a binding of GNU readline library](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Movement-Commands), which,
as Bash manual page says, is what handles reading input when using an
interactive shell.

> **clear-screen (C-L)**
> Clear the screen leaving the current line at the top of the screen.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> binding can be reassigned in `.inputrc`.

---

`clear`, on the other hand, is an external command.

```
$ type clear
clear is /usr/bin/clear
```

From its [manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ncurses-bin/clear.1.en.html),

> `clear` clears your screen if this is possible, **including its scrollback buffer**
> (if the extended “E3” capability is defined).
>
> OPTIONS
> `-x`   do not attempt to clear the terminal's scrollback buffer using the
> extended “E3” capability.

Comment: Unfortunatelly,  current behaviour of a cygwin bash make ctrl-l to erase scrollback as well.

Answer (score 8):

Use `tput reset`

Thanks to this answer: [What commands can I use to reset and clear my terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/122911/bash-reset-and-clear-commands/123185#123185)

Answer (score 7):

the `clear` command does not clear scrollback for me.  so `clear` or ^L works.

Answer (score 5):

In newer versions of clear, it seems that the default behaviour has been changed.
To clear the screen and keep scrollback use the option `-x`.
To have the previous behaviour create an alias such as:

```
alias clear='clear -x'
```

Comment: `clear -x` also works great in non-interactive bash scripts.

Answer (score 3):

If you pipe the output to `less`, then not only will it clear the screen and show your output at the top, but it will switch back to the previous screen contents when you exit.

Comment: Good point, `less` is powerful. But it's not quite what I'm looking for. If it outputs "less" than a full screen it doesn't start at the top and, as you allude to, it doesn't get added to the scrollback.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOs and using vi-mode I added this to my `~/.inputrc`:

```
$if mode=vi

set keymap vi-insert
Control-w: "^[dBxi "
Control-l: 'clear\n'

$endif
```

Then in my bashrc I have this function:

```
# clear screen and save scrollback
clear() {
    printf "\\033[H\\033[22J"
}
```