# Linux clear console

Tags: linux, unix, console, terminal, kde

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bash: Reset and Clear Commands](https://superuser.com/questions/122911/bash-reset-and-clear-commands)

I know about Linux command clear, but it just moves previous output from visible part of terminal window (KDE Konsole). I can still scroll up and see all previous text.
Is there similar command that can erase entire content of a terminal window?
Something like clc in matlab.

Comment: Maybe you mean Konsole then, instead of console. The history is a setting inside each terminal application, normally called scrollback. And I think under Edit, is Clear History

Answer (score 1):

clear should clear the entire terminal, as far as I know. reset might be what you're looking for.

Also, this should be in the super user stack overflow.

Comment: same thing with reset :(

Comment: :O the Super User Stack Overflow!! My brain just had a Stack Overflow...