# Clearing Terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

The linux terminal has a handy command named "clear" that removes all previous output. Unfortunately, when I run this command and then compile a rather large project with gcc, all previous output magically reappears in the terminal. This makes it hard to find errors and things.

Is there some way to *permanently* clear the terminal in Ubuntu?

Edit: I think it's bash - it's whatever the default for Ubuntu 10.04 is. Anyway, `reset` worked.

Comment: what terminal are you using? (`bash`, `csh`, etc.)?

Comment: @NateKoppenhaver: `terminal` != `shell` ... the terminal is the program which displays the output of the shell and forwards the input of the user to the shell. `terminal` is something like `xterm`, `urxvt`, `konsole`, `gnome-terminal` etc...

Comment: @Jake: since the terminal holds the rendered text of the shell it is important to know which `terminal` you use...

Comment: @Jake: On your edit: As akira said, *bash* is not a terminal. It's a shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found a better alternative to this. I use the following command:

```
alias clear=`echo -en "\ec"'
```

This removes everything from the current terminal window, similar to the default `clear` command, but the content is actually purged rather than just hidden a page up.

The reset command is probably more portable but it's also slower and does a lot more than just removing the visible text from the window.

Here is some further explanation:

[What commands can I use to reset and clear my terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/122911/bash-reset-and-clear-commands)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming are you using `Bash`.

`Clear` command, just "move the page down". Clearing the current terminal view, but history is kept.

You should use the `reset` to *permanently* clear the terminal.