# PuTTY: clear scrollback from commandline

Tags: putty

When I connect to my server via PuTTY, I can clear the visible screen with the `clear` command.

However, I can still scroll backwards in PuTTY's GUI to see the old stuff.
I am aware of PuTTY's [Clear Scrollback](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#i68) feature, but that requires mouse clicking.

I'd like to perform that exact same "Clear Scrollback" operation, but from the commandline.

Is it possible?

I read [this site](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/term-clear-scrollback.html), which seems to indicate so.

However, my experiments have failed.
For instance:

```
printf '\033[3J'
```

Does nothing, for me.

I may not be understanding the meaning of `CSI 3 J` in that second link, though...

Comment: What version of PuTTY are you using? The page indicates the feature works in PuTTY 0.59 and above. I have PuTTY 0.60 and it works for me. Note it only clears the scrollback buffer, it doesn't clear the screen. (If I have a scroll bar I can actually scroll, then use this sequence, I notice the scroll bar become disabled because there's suddenly nothing available to scroll to. But the currently displayed screen remains in place.)

Comment: @Bavi_H: ah, thank you - I was not realizing that it won't affect the currently displayed text. I see it is working, too. The full solution I want is `clear && printf '\033[3J'`. If you make an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `CSI 3 J` sequence to clear the scrollback buffer was added to PuTTY 0.59. (On the [wish request page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/term-clear-scrollback.html) for this feature see the "fixed-in" line, or go to the PuTTY [changes](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/changes.html) page and search for `CSI 3 J`.)

As jwd mentioned, you can enter `printf '\033[3J'` on a command line to send this sequence to the PuTTY. Be aware this only clears the scrollback buffer, it doesn't clear the screen. If you have a scroll bar you can actually scroll, then use this sequence, you'll see the scroll bar become disabled because there's suddenly nothing available to scroll to. But the currently displayed screen remains in place.

As jwd mentioned, you can clear both the screen and the scrollback buffer using `clear && printf '\033[3J'`

Comment: And for those seeking some light reading about control codes: https://www.xfree86.org/4.8.0/ctlseqs.html     (:  This one is in under `CSI P s J`

Comment: We can replace `clear && printf '\033[3J'` by `printf '\033[2J'` that's erase all.

Answer (score 15):

If you're accustomed, as I am, to using <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> for the `Reset terminal` option available in PuTTY's system menu, then you might find it helpful to enable `Configuration -> Window -> Behavior -> "System menu appears on ALT-Space"`.

Then when you hit <kbd>Alt+Space</kbd>, the option for `"Clear scrollback"` is triggered by <kbd>L</kbd> (lowercase; no Shift).  Thus, `reset + clear` becomes the charmingly-mnemonic combination of <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> and <kbd>Alt+Space</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> without any pesky mousing or clutter in your shell history.

Comment: Works and is easy to remember :)

Comment: Not bad, though FYI: you can also prevent cluttering your shell history by prefixing a command with a space.

Answer (score 10):

Create a script file and place it in a path-included folder:

```
$cat > /usr/local/bin/cls
#!/bin/bash
printf '\033[2J\033[H\033[3J'
```

Press CTRL+d to save and exit

Change permission on file:

```
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/cls
```

Now you can use the cmd `cls`

Comment: Use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash`, which does not work on my system.

Answer (score 5):

There is an option in PuTTY where you can uncheck the default scrollback behaviour.

Just uncheck the option "Push erased text into scrollback".

[image: Putty Settings image]

After this when you issue the `clear` command it will erase the screen and will not put the previous screen contents in the scrollback.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to transmit '\033\143' characters:

> printf("\033\143");

This clears the terminal screen and puts the cursor back in the upper left corner.

Comment: (1) The question asks for a command-line (i.e., shell) command.  This is not a shell command, it is a line of C code; as such, it is not an answer to this question.  (2) This post would be slightly more useful if you said what the `\143` character is, and how it relates to this question, ideally with citations.

Comment: For those wondering, this corresponds to the "full reset" escape code (`ESC c`). ASCII `c` has value `99` which is octal `143`. This will do a bunch of other things in addition to clearing the scrollback, just FYI.