# Clear console in Linux command prompt

Tags: linux, command-line

I know cls and clear exist. But after using these commands I can still scroll up and see my history. I want it to behave like a real reopening of the window.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other stated, `reset` should do the trick. However, some terminal emulator (`mintty` from Cygwin if I'm right) doesn't even clear the scrollback buffer. In this case, they should have an option to do that directly. In `mintty` there is something like "Clear scrollback" when you do a right click in the window, or open the menu.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's indeed selectable in the Putty right click menu

Answer (score 3):

Try `reset`: this clears the scrollback buffer in the terminal programs I've tried (`xfce4-terminal`, `gnome-terminal` and `xterm`).

Comment: works in Terminal.app on os X too, BTW.

Comment: If I do `reset` then it says: `Erase is control-H (^H).`. And control-H does nothing

Comment: but does it clear your scrollback?

Comment: No, my cursor is moved to top (like cls does) but I can still scroll up and see my history

Comment: Can you tell us what shell and terminal program you're using?

Comment: I'm using Putty and I have xterm terminal. I connect using SSH

Answer (score 1):

In some terminals (xterm), *ctrl-L* clears the screen like `reset`, but faster. However in gnome-terminal *ctrl-L* behaves like `clear`.

*Since I can't yet comment, just want to point out that Putty provides it's own terminal, unleses you use X11 tunneling.*

Edit:

If you wish to clear the scrollback buffer via the command-line, use a previous superuser answer [PuTTY: clear scrollback from commandline](https://superuser.com/a/555590/305146). This can be aliased as `alias reset="clear && printf '\033[3J'"`.

Comment: ctrl-L adds a new blank line. It doesn't do what I wanted. But thanks for your post