# How do I send the `CSI 3 J` sequence to my putty session?

Tags: putty

How do I send the `CSI 3 J` sequence to my putty session?

I'm trying to clear the scrollback buffer in my putty session using the method found in this post:

[PuTTY: clear scrollback from commandline](https://superuser.com/questions/555554/putty-clear-scrollback-from-commandline)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the comments of the referenced post.

From the command line:

`clear && printf '\033[3J'`